# Attach CSS on a newly opened browser window

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, reference

I'm trying to open a new browser window that contains the retrieved view and its data using ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: redirectToANewWindow,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { filterValue: searchValue },
            success: function (result) {
              var NewBrowserWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=500,width=900,scrollbars=yes,location=no');
              $(NewBrowserWindow.document.body).html(result);
            }
    });
```

The fields, as well as its data are displayed on the newly opened browser. But the returned view has no CSS on it so all the fields are messy. My main CSS is declared somewhere else and for some reason, I can't declare it inside my returned view. My question is, how can I return this view and attach a CSS file with it?

I've tried this,

```
success: function (result) {
     var styles = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../Content/GlobalStyle.css' />";
     var NewBrowserWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=500,width=900,scrollbars=yes,location=no');
     $(NewBrowserWindow .document.head).html(styles);
}
```

But it doesn't work although I can see the CSS reference added on the html. Is it that it just can't locate the file I referenced?

Im using **MVC** by the way.

Comment: Why don't you try put the css on the page/view itself?

Comment: Because my CSS is declared on master page and is used by several Partial Views. And the view I'm returning is just a single Partial View of that master page. I'll have to declare it twice if I do that. And I think its a common practice to put your CSS declaration on your master page

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$('<link/>', {
       rel: 'stylesheet',
       type: 'text/css',
       href: '../Content/GlobalStyle.css'
    }).appendTo('Head');
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. I get the same result like the solution I've stated on my question. The <link> tag is appended but it seems like it's not executed.

Comment: please tell your jQuery version please and which browser you r looking into

Comment: Im using version 1.7.1 and testing it on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Untested code but try this:

```
var addStylesheetTo = function(url, target) {
    var link = $('<link/>');
    link.attr({
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: url
    });
    $(target).append(link);
};

addStylesheetTo('/the/url/of/your/stylesheet.css', NewBrowserWindow.document.head);
```